# How to export a resource name and use in different Cloudformation Stackset?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I created a CloudFormation Stackset that deployed AWS Config Rules to two accounts.  Now I want to create a stackset that deploys the Remediation. the bottom lines of code work when I have it all in one CFT.  but I want to deploy te detection rules in one script first then the remediation rules second. How can I reference the S3BucketEncryptionEnabled Resource from a different scipt?

```
---------------------Detection --------------------------------------------------------
 S3BucketEncryptionEnabled:
    Type:  AWS::Config::ConfigRule
    Properties:
      Description: Checks that your Amazon S3 bucket either has S3 default encryption enabled or that the S3 bucket policy explicitly denies put-object requests without server side encryption.
      Source:
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: S3_BUCKET_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED
      Scope:
        ComplianceResourceTypes:
          - AWS::S3::Bucket
    DependsOn: ConfigRecorder

----------------------Remediation Script-----------------------------------------------
BasicRemediationConfiguration:
    Type: "AWS::Config::RemediationConfiguration"
    Properties:
        Automatic: True
        MaximumAutomaticAttempts: 5
        RetryAttemptSeconds: 60
        ConfigRuleName: !Ref S3BucketEncryptionEnabled
        Parameters:
            AutomationAssumeRole:
                StaticValue:
                    Values: [{"Fn::GetAtt" : ["S3Role","Arn"]}]       
                    
            BucketName:
                ResourceValue:
                    Value: RESOURCE_ID


            SSEAlgorithm:
                StaticValue:
                    Values: [AES256]
        TargetId: "AWS-EnableS3BucketEncryption"
        TargetType: "SSM_DOCUMENT"
        TargetVersion: "1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, in your `Detection` template you would [export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html) the  `S3BucketEncryptionEnabled` in your outputs.

For example:

```
Outputs:

    S3BucketEncryptionEnabled:
        Value: !Ref S3BucketEncryptionEnabled
        Export:
            Name: MyS3BucketEncryptionEnabled
```

Then in your `Remediation` template, you would use [ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) to import the exported value.

For example:

```
BasicRemediationConfiguration:
    Type: "AWS::Config::RemediationConfiguration"
    Properties:
        Automatic: True
        MaximumAutomaticAttempts: 5
        RetryAttemptSeconds: 60
        ConfigRuleName: !ImportValue MyS3BucketEncryptionEnabled
        # remaining properties
```